# Component property not considered on runtime in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, properties, runtime, components, design-time

I am developing a component but I can't make it consider a property set  at design-time.

The following is an excerpt of the component:

```
TRVEditFrame = class(TFrame)
...
    private
     { Private declarations }
        FRVEditor:TCustomRichView;
    public
     { Public declarations }
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    protected
        function GetRVEditor:TCustomRichView;
        procedure SetRVEditor(Editor:TCustomRichView);
    published
        property RVEditor:TCustomRichView read GetRVEditor write SetRVEditor;
    end;
...

constructor TRVEditFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    SetRVEditor(FRVEditor);
...
end;


function TRVEditFrame.GetRVEditor:TCustomRichView;
begin
    Result:=FRVEditor;
end;


procedure TRVEditFrame.SetRVEditor(Editor:TCustomRichView);
begin
    if Assigned(Editor) then begin
        FRVEditor:=Editor;
    end;
end;
```

I can register the component, place it in ther form and set FRVEditor on design-time.

Problem is when I run the application the code inside SetRVEditor() is not executed because Editor=nil.

If I was able to set FRVEditor on design-time, how come that it is=nil on run time ? How can I fix this ?

---

I add here my further comments because the explanation is too long

@Kenneth, thank you for your reply

- TCustomRichView is part of a third part component set that manages
  hypertext documents and has 4 more specialized descendents and you
  are right, TCustomRichView shouldn't be used in a real application.
- TRVEditFrame is the component I am developing.

The idea behind my component is to create one single frame (hence the choice of the component TFrame) with menus, shortcuts, popup menus etc to manage each of the 4 TCustomRichView descendents.

This is exactly the reason why I use TCustomRichView: I can "slot" any of the 4 descendents into my component-frame. This is the same principle of TDatasource that can be connected with TTAble and TQuery (they have the same ancestor).

I suppose the reason why the VCL doesn't link RVEditor to the TCustomRichView descendent I set on design-time is because TFrame has no OnCreate event, like TForm for instance.

So far I managed to solve the issue by calling TRVEditFrame.SetRVEditor manually in the TForm.OnCreate that hosts TRVEditFrame but I was wondering if there are better methods to do so and that is why I have asked advice here.

I know you can create a OnCreate event for TFrames as well, maybe I can place TRVEditFrame.SetRVEditor in there but, again, I was wondering if there was a better method.

Regarding the last part of your comment, I am aware of the register procedure but take into account the component is under development. When I develope components I never install them in the IDE because I prefer to keep the test stuff outside the "official" one. 
I use this method and as soon as the component is ready then I register it with the procedure you mention. If I want to implement other features to the same component I can work on the test ones and keep on using the "official" one I have in the IDE at the same time.

Comment: What is TCustomRichView? It looks like a class. So the
property is a reference. Where is the actual object? Does it exist on a form? Has the object even been instantiated before it is used as the source of the property assignment?
Also, that SetRVEditor(FRVEditor) in the constructor is
pointless. Get rid of it.

Comment: @David 
TcustomerRichView is a class and the property is a reference to another class to be linked

Yes, the object is dropped in the same form at design-time as TRVEditFrame.

"Has the object even been instantiated before it is used as the source of the property assignment?"
I am not sure of what you mean here. TRVEditFrame.RVEditor is designated at design time. Did I answer your question

Comment: @pio pio: when you take a look at the DFM (alt+F12), do you see the property set to the value you assigned?

Comment: @AlexSC 
Yes, the property RVEditor is set to the correct object

Comment: @pio pio: would you  tell us which Delphi version are you using? Are you using visual form inheritance with this frame?

Comment: I have Delphi XE2 and I inherited my class directly from TFrame

Comment: @pio pio: Is the TCustomRichView descendent placed **over** the TRVEditFrame?

Comment: @AlexSC: TCustomRichView is placed inside TRVEditFrame. As I mention TRVEditFrame is a frame around one of the TCustomRichView descendents. You can compare TRVEditFrame to the menu bar+rulers+status bar of an editor and TCustomRichView descendent to the place where the text is typed by the user.

Comment: @pio pio: well, I guess this explains! I believe that the deserialization of the DFM won´t work, because the reference to the inner component (the one inside the frame) is still nil when it read. Sorry, but I believe the design as it is won´t work. My suggestion for you is to connect the frame to the inner component by using the Notification method and setting an internal data member to it. The nice thing of this new design is that nobody will have to set any properties. Just dropping one component over the other will get all done!

Comment: @AlexSC `TCustomRichView` may be turned into a var rather than property, then it might be created by the frame - but the frame would only create the named class while the topic starter wants it to be any random descendant determined at runtime. Some some extra infoe should be what the class actually is to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to change the design in order to get the frame component referencing the custom editor by using the Notification method, instead of manually setting a property. So, change your frame class to

```
TRVEditFrame = class(TFrame)
...
private
 { Private declarations }
    FRVEditor: TCustomRichView;
protected
  procedure Notification(aComponent: TComponent; aOperation: TOperation); override;
public
 { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
public
    property RVEditor:TCustomRichView read FRVEditor;
end;
```

The implementation of the Notification method does the magic of connecting/disconnecting the frame to the custom editor

```
procedure TRVEditFrame.Notification(aComponent: TComponent;
                                    aOperation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if aComponent is TCustomRichView then
    if aOperation=opRemove then begin
      if aComponent=FRVEditor then
        FRVEditor := nil;
    end else
      FRVEditor := TCustomRichView(aComponent);
end;
```

I don´t know if you need any special handling when an editor is set/reset to the frame, so this code does nothing in special, just assigns the component or nil to the FRVEditor data member at the proper moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should create child components.

```
constructor TRVEditFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited; // Create(AOwner);
    FRVEditor := TRichView.Create(self);
end;
```

DFM streaming engine may load properties of already created class, but it cannot create the class for you for two reasons:

1) DFM can not know of any special tuning done on created component, like what should be constructor parameters (if any), what constructor to use (of many), which niotifications and event handlers to attach and so on.

2) DFM can not know which type the property should be. For example i published `TStrings` oroperty - object of which class should be created to feel in ? `TStrings`? `TStringList`? `TRichEditStringList`? `THashedStringList` ? they all were inherited from `TStrings` and thus any of them is fine choice for DFM - but not for the ocmponent you write.

Thus DFM streaming subsystem is responsible for saving and loading properties of objects, but creating those object is purely your responsibility.

---

I believe you also may cut the corners by learning how IDE Designer creates your forms and making `RVEdit` a variable rather than property:

```
TRVEditFrame = class(TFrame)
...
    public
     { Public declarations }
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    published
        var RVEditor:TCustomRichView; // just like users' forms are created by IDE
    end;
```

Then hopefully `TFrame` constructor would create the content for this variable for you.  But this design is fragile because any outer code would be able by any stupid mistake to make something like `MyEditFrame.RVEditor := ...` and cause a memory leak and unexpected failures of all the attached connections between the editor and the frame.

Comment: The purpose of TRVEditFrame is to create a component that can "host" one of the 4 TCustomRichView descendents, as I explain in my notes above. If I assign FRVEditor := TRichView.Create(self) in the constructor then TRVEditFrame will be able to work with TRichView only.

Comment: Then make it create any of descendants as you wish.
If you want - make an extra published property to save `.ClassName` of the selected descendant.
But DFM streaming does not create classes for properties, for the outlined reasons. `TReader` can NOT know which class there should be so it should be YOU creating the proper class object

Comment: so you are saying I have to call TRVEditFrame.SetRVEditor in the TForm.OnCreate. Am I correct ?

Comment: guess it would be too late - since Delphi 4 it AFAIR would be after DFM streaming already finished. But you may intercept it and `TForm.Loaded` and see which one is called 1st. `Loaded` is called right after DFM parsed, so you would see. But i think you'd rather do it in `TForm.AfterConstruction` instead. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.AfterConstruction

Comment: However i outlined another approach that is think is better. I repeat: in `TRVEditFrame` you make an extra published 
`AnsiString` property to save `.ClassName` of the selected descendant. In runtime you register all your implementations of RVEditors - `RegisterClasses` - and when that AnsiString property would be read you find the class by name and crate its instance. And make sure that `classname property` would be read before `RVEditor` properties and can only be changed while `FRVEditor` is still `nil` and cannot be changed after the editor is already created